# to_char(Column_name) what would be the column name in dataset

Tags: sql, oracle, dataset, column-alias

I have a column name  as CREATEDATE. I use this sqlcommand to get the information

```
string sql = "SELECT USERID,USERNAME,USERPOSITION,UPDATEUSERID,USERSTATUS,TO_CHAR(CREATEDATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM USERMASTER WHERE USERID ='" + stat[0] + "'";
```

I bind them in to dataset ds.

when I want to get the data of `TO_CHAR(CREATEDATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')`

I try to assign this way.

```
lblCreatedOn.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["TO_CHAR(CREATEDATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')"].ToString();
```

its throw me an error call Column '`TO_CHAR(CREATEDATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')`' does not belong to table Table.

anyone know what the column would be?

Comment: Try with alias as `TO_CHAR(CREATEDATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS "CREATEDATE"`

Comment: @LalitKumarB  
this method work perfectly fine! u add the answer below. I will vote for you. thanks a lots!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes in few applications, the alias needs the keyword **`AS`** to qualify as an alias. Or, may be you need **quoted identifier**, i.e. use **double-quotation marks**.

So, modify it as:

```
TO_CHAR(CREATEDATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS "CREATEDATE"
```